# How to call custom name funtion

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to figure, how to call  a specific function name in WepApi.

Currently if i call the WebApi with that structure `api/{controllerName`
its working (in case that the function name start with "get")

What i am trying to accomplish is that:

### in JS

```
  $http.get("http://localhost:34662/api/webapi/CustomfunctionName/")
                                .then(function (response) {
                                    vm.employees = response.data;
                                }
```

### in WebApi

```
 [HttpGet]
    [Route(Name = "CustomfunctionName")]
    public IEnumerable<tblEmployees> CustomfunctionName()
    {
        using (Entities entities = new Entities())
        {
            return entities.tblEmployees.ToList();
        }
    }
```

I also tried to add a decorator above the function in the WebApi:

```
[Route(Name = "CustomfunctionName")]
```

but it didn't help.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Could you add ***RoutePrefix*** attribute at the controller, and try again?

```
[RoutePrefix("api/webapi")]
public class WebApiController : ApiController
{
   [HttpGet]
   [Route("CustomfunctionName")]
   public IEnumerable<tblEmployees> CustomfunctionName()
   {
   }
}
```

Solution per @E.Meir: If you use [ActionName(...)], you should decorate it to every action method inside the controller.

Comment: `angular_1.6.4.js:12587 GET http://localhost:34662/api/webapi/CustomfunctionName 400 (Bad Request)`

Comment: `angular_1.6.4.js:14525 Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":{"Message":"The request is invalid.","MessageDetail":"The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable`

Comment: Routing has an issue. Could you create a new controller with one action method? For example, TestController. Then try `http://localhost:34662/api/test/CustomfunctionName` inside browser or use Chrome Postman, as it is just simple HttpGet.

Comment: ok, i found the problem, i have another function with `[HttpGet]`decorator , the function name is different, nut it didn't have `[ActionName("..")` when i added `ActionName` with other name- it started working.

Comment: if you think that it will help others, please write it as answer - that if u use `[ActionName(` then you should decorate each of the other functions with that also (but with different name)